Proving that for every semi-Thue system $\Gamma$, there exists a two-letter semi-Thue system $\Gamma'$ such that $S_\Gamma = S_{\Gamma'}$
I'm reading Martin Davis' Computabilty and Unsolvability. In Chapter 6, Section 1, Davis writes the following:

THEOREM 1.8. For every semi-Thue system $\Gamma$, we can construct a semi-Thue system $\Gamma'$ whose alphabet consists of two letters, such that $S_\Gamma = S_{\Gamma'}$.
PROOF: We construct $\Gamma^\ast$ as above. Then we form $\Gamma'$ by adjoining to $\Gamma^*$ the production
$$ P1b1Q \rightarrow P1Q. $$
Then we have
$$ \begin{aligned} n \in S_\Gamma & \leftrightarrow {}\vdash_\Gamma 1^{n+1} \\ & \leftrightarrow {}\vdash_{\Gamma^\ast} (1b1)^{n+1} \\ & \leftrightarrow {}\vdash_{\Gamma'} 1^{n+1} \\ & \leftrightarrow n \in S_{\Gamma'}. \end{aligned}$$

Here $\Gamma^*$ is a combinatorial system whose alphabet consists only of two letters $a_0 = 1$ and $a_ 1= b$, and whose decision problem is recursively solvable if and only if that for $\Gamma$ is, where the rule of transformation is $a_i^\ast = 1b^{i+1}1$.
I understand how to get from $n \in S_\Gamma$ to $n\in S_{\Gamma'}$. However, I am stuck proving that $n \in S_{\Gamma'}$ implies $n \in S_\Gamma$. I do not understand how ${}\vdash_{\Gamma'} 1^{n+1}$ implies ${}\vdash_{\Gamma^\ast} (1b1)^{n+1}$.
I tried thinking about the different cases. In this scenario, as $\Gamma'$ is an "extension" of $\Gamma^\ast$, then if $1^{n+1}$ is a theorem in $\Gamma'$, either:

$(1b1)^{n+1}$ is (already) a theorem of $\Gamma^\ast$ or;

The proof of $1^{n+1}$ in $\Gamma'$ uses the production $P1b1Q \rightarrow P1Q$.


However, how does this imply that it is necessarily the case that $(1b1)^{n+1}$ is a theorem in $\Gamma^\ast$? What am I missing? Is Davis using the inverse production?
(This is my first question, please tell me if I did something wrong.)

Welcome!  Great first question, thanks for your contribution!  I hope someone here can answer your question.
